# Azurerm diagnostic setting

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a diagnostic setting for a storage account. Terraform says the 'log' sub block  is deprecated and to use 'enabled_log'. I've passed variations of 'all' and 'allLogs' to category and category_group. Neither has yielded any positive outcomes. I have my code below. I was told this is the place even hiring managers come to get their questions answered. I need some help if you can spare it.

Create a diagnostic setting

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "ttntemsilverstorage" {   
name  = var.name   
target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.ttsilverkv.id   
storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.devstorageacct.id    
enabled_log 
{     
  category = "AuditEvent"    
  enabled_log {     
  category = "allLogs"     
}    
metric {     
category = "AllMetrics"     
enabled = true 
     }   
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried so far? @user23350878

Comment: resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "ttntemsilverstorage" {
  name               = var.name
  target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.ttsilverkv.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.devstorageacct.id

  enabled_log {
    category = "AuditEvent"

  enabled_log {
    category = "allLogs"


  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
    enabled = true
}
  }
}

Comment: `resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "ttntemsilverstorage" {
  name               = var.name
  target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.ttsilverkv.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.devstorageacct.id

  enabled_log {
    category = "AuditEvent"

  enabled_log {
    category = "allLogs"


  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
    enabled = true
}
  }
}`

Comment: Have you tried the updated one. @user23350878

Answer (score 0):

Firstly yes as error shows, `'log'` block is deprecated and `'enabled_log'` has to be used in place of it.
,
Refer [argument reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting.html#argument-reference) from terraform registry template here.

And you cannot pass`allLogs` to a `category or category groups` directly to create a diagnostic setting and enable logs for the storage account. Instead follow below steps to achieve the requirement.

To enable logging for storage account type, you can create diagnostic settings at various levels like blob, queue etc... as shown in below image.

[image]

In order to achieve it, you need to enable diagnostic setting first and then enable logs for all categories by passing `"StorageWrite," "StorageRead," and "StorageDelete"` operations under `enabled_log` property within the diagnostic settings as shown clearly below.

*Enabling diagnostic settings:*

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "sample-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "firstjahstore"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                       = "firstjahvault"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = false
  sku_name                   = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
  }
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

*Enabling logs for different categories:*

```bash
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
name = "sample-resources"
}
data "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                = "firstjahstore"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
 resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "main" {
   name               = "storagelogs"
   target_resource_id = "${data.azurerm_storage_account.main.id}/blobServices/default"
   storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.main.id
   enabled_log {
    category = "StorageRead"
   }
   
   enabled_log {
    category = "StorageWrite"
   }

   enabled_log {
    category = "StorageDelete"
   }

   metric {
     category = "Transaction"
   }
 }
```

*Output:*

[image]

[image]

*Reference:*

1. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421183/19785512) link
2. Use this resource [`azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/monitor_diagnostic_categories) to access more information on the specific diagnostic setting categories.